# Django can't display the image saved in the database

Tags: django, python-3.x

I wrote two templates in Django "index.html" and "detail.html". In both templates, I display png, in the template "index" the graphics are displayed correctly, and in the template "detail" has the status "src (unknown)".

detail.html (details.html should display only one graphic)

```
<section class="jumbotron text-center">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="jumbotron-heading">Course Detail</h1>
        <p class="lead text-muted"> {{ films.summary}}.</p>
        <img class = "card-img" src="{{film.image.url}}" > </img>
        <p>
          <a href="{% url 'index' %}" class="btn btn-primary my-2">Back</a>
        </p>

      </div>
    </section>
```

index.html

```
  <div class="row">
        {% for film in films.all %}
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">

        <a href="{% url 'detail' film.id %}">
          <img class = "card-img" src="{{film.image.url}}" > </img>
            </a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text"> {{film.summary}}  </p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}



  </div>
</div>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import Films

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    films = Films.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'films/index.html',{'films':films})


def detail(request, films_id):
    films_detail = get_object_or_404(Films,pk=films_id)

    return render(request, 'films/detail.html',{'films':films_detail})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('<int:films_id>', views.detail, name="detail"),
]
```

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, I noticed the error in the code :)

Comment: Current detail.html

Comment: <main role="main">

        <section class="jumbotron text-center">
          <div class="container">
            <h1 class="jumbotron-heading">Course Detail</h1>
            <p class="lead text-muted"> {{ films.summary}}.</p>
            <img class = "card-img" src="{{films.image.url}}" > </img>
            <p>
              <a href="{% url 'index' %}" class="btn btn-primary my-2">Back</a>
            </p>
      
          </div>
        </section>

      
      </main>

Answer (score 0):

Before going to display any image you should make your url.py  inform about it, So the right way to do this is by creating following MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL in setting.py

**Managing Media**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

After that import this in url.py from setting and add it to urlpatterns

**Adding URL**

```
    urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

After adding this Django will Definitely Recognize your URL

## The real problem in your code is that you are passing films(as Dictionary) from views.py but assessing it in templates as film

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Films
def index(request):
    films = Films.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'films/index.html',{'films':films})
def detail(request, films_id):
    films_detail = get_object_or_404(Films,pk=films_id)
    return render(request, 'films/detail.html',{'films':films_detail})
```

index.html

```
`  <div class="row">
        {% for film in films.all %}
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
        <a href="{% url 'detail' films.id %}">
          <img class = "card-img" src="{{films.image.url}}" > </img>
            </a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text"> {{films.summary}}  </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>`
```

detail.html

```
<section class="jumbotron text-center">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="jumbotron-heading">Course Detail</h1>
        <p class="lead text-muted"> {{ films.summary}}.</p>
        <img class = "card-img" src="{{film.image.url}}" > </img>
        <p>
          <a href="{% url 'index' %}" class="btn btn-primary my-2">Back</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
```